# Algorithm for tiling a surface with no adjacent tiles

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for an algorithm that does as follows:

> Given a 2D grid of X,Y and a number of tiles T, places a tile in each cell of the grid such that the surrounding tiles are not the same.

This should also ideally be capable of providing a random seed to randomize the output.

I understand that for not all values of X, Y and T this is possible, but is there an existing algorithm that will do what I'm looking for? I'm currently using a naive hand-rolled implementation that doesn't always provide the best results.

Is something like a constraint solver what I need?

Comment: What do you mean by "best results?"  How large are these grids?

Comment: "Not best results" in that sometimes adjacent tiles appear. The grid can be any size, i.e. user-defined.

Comment: Sounds like a [Coloring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring). There is a lot of research and options as to how to solve them.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If you want a grid to be tiled with non-adjacent tiles, just use a checkerboard pattern. What am I not seeing?

Comment: The pattern needs to be random. Think tiling a surface in a 3D scene with different tiles in order to hide repeating patterns. Along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Randomly distribute the most numerous tile so that there are no adjacencies.  Then randomly distribute the next most numerous tile, and so on.  That should work well unless the two most numerous tiles cover almost the entire rectangle.